# I was outsourced. Can former co-worker keep requesting passwords?

Tags: outsourcing

Three months ago, I was suddenly (for me) told I was outsourced, a business decision.
After this, I got vacation, etc. plus a severance.

It was sudden for me, but upon reflection I realize they were quiet about firing me, because the consulting company kept asking for server, information and passwords, etc., and then I discovered I was being excluded from meetings I should have been included on that my former coworker was included on.

My former coworker keeps asking me for passwords. A few I remembered and provided, and I know other passwords were documented on the laptop computer I ethically returned.

I'm no longer an employee, so I think from now on my answer should be 'No.' On some previous requests I simply did not reply and the requested information was found anyway.

Particularly for today's request which I really don't remember anyway and it's annoying because I am no longer an employee!

I am sure I documented it and they will find it.

This coworker offered to provide a reference (he claimed to be surprised what happened. I actually think he was in on it, but I don't have any proof), so I also feel like I have to stay on his good side. I only have two other references.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140171/discussion-on-question-by-parkaboy-i-was-outsourced-can-former-co-worker-keep-r).

Comment: What do you mean by "I was outsourced"? Usually it's work that would be outsourced, not people... Do you mean you are now an employee of another company doing the same work for your former company? Or do you mean you were laid off?

Comment: @komodosp it means that he was laid off and its former job was assigned to a third party company.

Comment: @o0'. As discussed in comments now [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140171/discussion-on-question-by-parkaboy-i-was-outsourced-can-former-co-worker-keep-r), that's probably correct but I'd *really* like to see a response from the OP rather than assuming what they meant.

Answer (score 194):

If it wasn't part of the severance agreement, I don't think you are required to do anything for that company.

You can even make a claim that information security policies prevent you from doing so because you have no way to verify that are entitled to that information after you left the job. If they use your passwords, they might later blame you if something goes wrong if the password transfer is not documented.

Comment: Further, granting secrets of this nature to individuals not authorized to possess them is a breach of security. Be mindful of the penalties for breaching corporate security: they are not necessarily limited to the duration of your employment.

Comment: If I have the access, I'll shut off my account or even get them locked by repeatedly failing them. I don't even WANT access after I left, regardless of whether they remember to turn them off or not.

Comment: @Nelson, I wouldn't even want it showing up in the logs that I was _attempting_ to access the system (to fail the logins and lock the account).

Comment: @spuck Yeah, you're right. That's probably not a good idea to lock your own account. Best to email the admin, cc your own boss and HR, and tell them to shut off your account.

Comment: Information security policies certainly *should* prevent OP from doing so, but it seems unlikely that they have good security practices. If they did, they wouldn't be asking an ex-employee for passwords. and those passwords wouldn't be usable if they did.

Answer (score 105):

You have left this company. Your only response now should be "I do not remember, nor do I have saved copies of, any passwords".

Make that true; if you have a 'password book', delete it. If you have 2FA for any systems, remove the 2FA item from your device. If you know a password to a system, and could potentially still access it, then you would be prime suspect if that system were ever compromised. Do not let yourself be caught in that situation.

Comment: This! Especially since OP doesn't seem to particularly trust the former colleague. If you even admit to knowing any passwords, you are leaving yourself open to accusations.

Comment: And, this answer does not burn bridges.

Comment: Came here to write this answer. Well done!   Admitting you still have passwords could tangle you up with hacking charges (if anything happens they could blame you). Also you are *subsidizing* an absolutely horrible security model that you should not support *in any way whatsoever*.

Comment: I would be shocked if your termination agreements etc, DIDN'T include a clause or agreement that you disposed of / deleted all of the company passwords that you had, and / or that you didn't have them recorded anywhere other than on the company machines which you've clearly surrendered. Clearly, you obeyed those provisions, CORRECT? Doing anything suggesting otherwise woud be ill-advised.

Comment: Two additional points regarding SSH keys:

#1 - Don't install personal SSH keys on any company servers.

#2- If the company requires you to access their servers from your home computer (not that common any more) then generate a new SSH key for that employer and copy the private key to your home computer.

That way when you leave you can delete the corporate private key from your computer in the same way that you delete your password book.

Comment: Indeed. First thing I do when leaving a job is to delete anything containing passwords and other credentials from my personal laptop (if I even had them on my personal laptop, and hadn't been using one provided by the customer/employer). That way the only remaining passwords are those I have only in my head, which would typically only be passwords to my personal accounts on their network, which shouldn't contain anything that's not available elsewhere on their network if at all useful to the company (source code, documents, not personal progress notes and experiments).

Answer (score 69):

You are no longer employed by them.

Either get them to pay you for your consultancy OR refuse further contact.

Comment: And by "them", Solar Mike means the company, not the random person asking for passwords.

Comment: "I'll be happy to help with that issue. My consulting fee is $100 per hour, with a minimum of 4 hours."

Comment: I'd be careful with the payment approach. In some jurisdictions, offering to provide passwords for a fee could be viewed as extortion. Much simpler just to decline.

Comment: @LaconicDroid is correct. Feel free to offer to consult for them -- it's their fault they didn't get as much from you as they need before they walked you out the door -- but not specifically to offer passwords for a price.

Comment: @LaconicDroid IANAL, but how could this be perceived as, or constitute, extortion? My understanding is that extortion requires coercion or duress - simply _capitalising_ (quite literally, heh) on a situation falls far short on that; and the OP’s former employer is well within their means to initiate password resets all by themselves (…assuming they didn’t outsource all their technically competent people) so it’s not like the OP is holding the company to ransom.

Comment: @Dai - if you approach the situtation as "I will give you the passwords if you pay me a nice consultancy fee" you may be on thin ice, as technically the passwords belong to the company. In Scotland, for example, there is a crime of "Extortion without menace".

Comment: @LaconicDroid I wanted to find out more but googling _""extortion without menace" scotland"_ gives me (literally) [zero results in google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Extortion+without+menace%22+scotland) : ([screenshot proof](https://imgur.com/T2I7EuS))

Comment: @Dai - try looking for "Black v Carmichael 1992 SCCR 709", [one link is here](https://vlex.co.uk/vid/black-and-another-v-807417965)

Comment: @LaconicDroid ta muchly

Comment: @Dai - The test case I was thinking of was actually from an incident where I lived. At the time I thought it was prosecuted as "extortion without menaces", but it seems the courts called it plain old "extortion and theft". Case is "Black v Carmichael 1992 SCCR 709", [one link is here](https://vlex.co.uk/vid/black-and-another-v-807417965).

Answer (score 46):

> I was outsourced, can former co-worker keep requesting passwords?

You are asking the wrong question. Obviously, former co-workers can ask for anything.

Instead you should be asking if you should supply passwords when asked.

The answer is clearly "No".

First, you are no longer employed there so it clearly isn't your job. Second, you shouldn't even know the current passwords - they should have been changed when you left.

Either ignore the requests, or just say "No".

Comment: Yeah, the fact that they are asking for passwords makes it weird. You don't even know if the guy asking for the password is supposed to have the password. He could be a disgruntled former employee too at this point! I'd probably cut some slack for calling up and asking about, say, some obscure config file option, but passwords make it weird.

Comment: Oh I know who the person is. I know the password is somewhere within the laptop I returned, no idea where though, my stuff was well organized, he probably found it already. Therefore I chose not to reply and he has not yet said anything, his new server management can just rebuild vSphere if they can't find what they want.

Comment: @Parkaboy you know who he is, but since you don't work at the company anymore, how do you know he's *still* authorized to receive the passwords?

Comment: Indeed. Just say "no." And the OP should have said "no" from the start. In addition, the OP might (as a gesture of goodwill) get in touch with his former manager and tell him/her this is happening and it makes him uncomfortable.

Comment: +1 for company should've changed the passwords. Long accepted practice in enterprise IT is to change admin/access passwords right-before, or at the same time as, the person is being terminated. In information-security, even minutes can cause a lot of harm.

Comment: @Parkaboy you did not scrub the laptop? Or was it a shared asset rather than personal?  There are protocols for resetting passwords and they will just have to wear it. A cost of outsourcing and poor IAM implementation.

Comment: @Parkaboy you may know the person, but do you have independent knowledge of his CURRENT security credentials? IOW do you KNOW he is currently authorised to have access to the systems he's trying to get you to provide him credentials to? Credentials which, as already mentioned, have, if this is a professional organisation, already been changed anyway if the system is at all sensitive (production servers, etc.).

Comment: @MandisaW indeed. First hint I had at a prior job that I was being terminated was suddenly being kicked from the network. I called IT support and they gave me the runabout, 15 minutes later HR called me... I was there as a contractor, so no termination period and they chose to pay the contract cancelation of 2 months work. Never did anything to lose their trust, was just standard procedure apparently for contractors to be treated that way when no longer needed.

Comment: @jwenting My late hubby also worked IT, but in Finance. Told a story about a guy's boss, HR, IT [him], and the FBI & SEC all showing up at the desk to revoke access *and* equipment. "You know you're fired when..."

Answer (score 30):

Since it sounds as though you did a proper handover of your passwords etc when you left you can just respond politely:

> All the login & password information I had has already been provided to *X* as part of my handover.

This is of course assuming you want to be polite - at this point you can just ignore them. If there's any login info you *didn't* provide at handover then refusing to engage can put you in a difficult position but if they (i.e. your former employer) has everything one way or another you can block/ignore the requests and carry on with the next phase of your career with a clear conscience and a spring in your step.

Comment: *If there's any login info you didn't provide at handover then refusing to engage can put you in a difficult position* Why? The handover conclusion was accepted by the company and the contract is over. I would refuse any consulting engagement about this because it implies I did not hand over everything (possibly on purpose)

Comment: There is no evidence for this in the question, but if OP intentionally tried to sabotage the company because he was being forced out, that would be an issue.  Say they had no access to an important server that OP set up, and the password they have does not work, and OP refuses to provide the password, and they later find out that OP changed the password the day they left to something that is not recorded, *that* would be an issue.

Comment: The fact that the employee *keeps* coming to him for passwords and he apparently provided some in the past leads me to believe they didn't have a good system for recording passwords, that some of them might be only in OP's head, and that OP did not diligently provide the employer with important information that would be needed by his employer after he left.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat Various jurisdictions will have different thresholds on liability for damages. Some require malicious intent, others just require recklessness. So I think you are correct, and it goes even beyond what you have said.

Answer (score 19):

The appropriate way to answer this is:

> I'm sorry, but I transferred all information and knowledge, including passwords, when my employment was terminated. Please do not continue to ask about this information, as I am no longer an employee of [company].  Further requests will not be answered.

This should be reasonably polite and not burn bridges with anyone who is being reasonable.  Of course, there's no saying how it will be received by the specific person here, and they might not be reasonable.

Comment: +1 not burning bridges and staying professional is on *longterm* always the best choice! Be polite, direct and clear.

Comment: Make sure it's in writing/timestamped (company AND personal email). Legally, you're responsible for anything you still have the passwords to, and the former employer / coworker can blame you for anything in your absence.

Answer (score 14):

If you are asked for a password, then ask yourself: Am I supposed to know that password? Normally when you leave your access to anything should be locked down, and the passwords that you know should be worthless. I wouldn't admit to knowing any passwords.

Comment: Right. When an employee leaves, all the passwords he knew or might have known should be changed as a matter of good practice.

Answer (score 7):

> My former co-worker keeps asking me for passwords. A few I remembered
> and provided,

This was your first mistake. You should have said that you didn't remember them the very first time you were asked. And you should have repeated a similar phrase every time the same request was made.

> I think from now on my answer should be 'No.'

Now your answer should be: "I've given you a notebook with all my passwords, and I've told you everything I could remember."

Be a broken record if you have to. It's not that difficult. Just don't adjust your response and don't try to justify yourself to try to gain his approval, otherwise, his requests will keep on coming.

But at the same time, take him up on his offer to give you a reference before his offer evaporates. Ask for a LinkedIn reference and offer to write a LinkedIn reference in return.
https://www.themuse.com/advice/your-5minute-guide-to-writing-an-amazing-linkedin-recommendation

Worst case scenario, his LinkedIn reference is not that good and you don't show it on your profile since you have the power to hide it if you don't like it. Best case scenario, he writes you a pretty good LinkedIn reference. Also, if any potential employer calls him, he will feel obligated to stick to what he wrote on your LinkedIn just to be consistent.

> (claimed to be surprised what happened, I actually think he was in on
> it but I have no proof)

So who cares if he was in on it?

Are you really telling us that if the situation had been reversed you would have told your colleague about the upcoming replacement?

And yes, he could be lying to you about his prior knowledge. But again, people tell each other white lies all the time. I'm sure you have as well.

I understand the hurt of being laid off, but do try to let go of that bitterness. It doesn't do you any good to blame him. Take him up on his offer and ask for a LinkedIn reference, but do tell him that you don't remember the passwords, which is the truth anyway. And to make the situation reciprocal, offer to give him a good LinkedIn reference in return.

But if he asks you anything else that's work related, just spell it out for him. "If this LinkedIn recommendation is contingent on me remembering a three months old password, then don't write one for me, because I can not give you what I don't remember". Or if he asks only about work, say: "If this LinkedIn recommendation is contingent on me consulting for free for a former employer three months after I was laid off from that employer, then please don't write such a recommendation for me."

And if you're still have trouble saying "No", I'd suggest you read this book [When I Say No, I Feel Guilty](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0553263900) by Manuel J. Smith. Personally, that book changed my life.

Comment: Maybe OPs former co-worker finds it easier to contact OP than to go through the official ways of asking IT to reset all those passwords.

Comment: I mean, I'm not sure on the "either the passwords are too simple, or you kept a copy of them for personal records"  - I can remember the (very secure) passwords from a few places I've worked, because I use easy to remember but secure password generating schemes, and because if you're working on linux servers, eventually something will brick badly enough that you have to log in in single user mode.

The difference here is that former places of work changed everything when I left. Rest of your answer is great though!

Comment: @lupe, You're right. I've amended my answer.

Comment: _"Are you really telling us that if the situation had been reversed you would have told your colleague about the upcoming replacement? No, I don't think so."_ I've been in that situation, the guy who got kicked out is still a good friend, and I would absolutely have risked my job and told him if I'd known it was coming. He told me he was going out for lunch (five years ago), and he still hasn't come back :)

Comment: @Auspex, Fair enough. It really does depend on the relationship you have with that colleague and on several other factors.

Comment: @Auspex - agree that this depends on relationships too - if I was friends with someone, I'd let them know it was coming. There's a danger here, though, because you often have an inkling that it is coming - like, new projects getting assigned to you, no plans being made for your co-workers, but aren't certain. I'm not sure how fair it is to share that speculation, unless you're 100% certain

Answer (score 4):

> I was outsourced, can former co-worker keep requesting passwords?

They can request whatever they want, that doesn't mean that you need to honor or acknowledge their requests in any way.

I have left companies where former coworkers would occasionally message or call me asking for work related help after I had left.  The former coworkers that I kept in touch with and had good relationships with I had no issue helping them at all.  The former coworkers that I did not care for, I never replied to their messages or answered their calls.

As for the reference, anyone offering a reference on the condition of your continued help after you have left the company is not worth it.

Answer (score 4):

Whether you documented the passwords or not, password management is an organization responsibility, not the responsibility of a singled employee. You owe them nothing more. If it were me, I'd simply ignore the requests.

Answer (score 3):

From now on assume you do not have any passwords.

First, they should have rotated them once you left.

You are probably in legal breach if you keep company information with you.

Finally, I would never accept a contract gig (as suggested elsewhere) for such assignments - you reveal that you kept that information and did not provide it at handover.

Do not reply to their requests, wait for a legal request that will never come because it makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: How would the OP be in legal breach if they knew a password which wasn't rotated? Should they beat themselves on the head with a baseball bat until they forget?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie: they were told during the handover to pass all credentials they had. They did not, and now want a consulting gig to provide it. This could be borderline and this is why I would never accept a contract position for that purpose. Of course if the company wants them to help run something, or reconfigure or whatever then fine. Since they leave the company on bad terms I would not take the risk and say that I do not have any other passwords and if I even had, I have forgotten them. The whole thing is a circus of course and the company is not serious - thus my careful treading

Comment: Right. But they will still "keep" the company information even if they hand it over, unless the passwords are reset. I would also say that if you were meant to handle credentials over, and didn't, and then "forgot" the passwords, they certainly can sue you over it. The remedy would include quantities of cash to compensate for the effort and costs of recovering the accounts/data as opposed to handing over the passwords.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie: once you leave the company after the handover and the company is fine with the outcome, it is the duty of the company to protect itself (by rotating the passwords). From your perspective, anything related to the company has *poof* gone from your mind. Sure this is a cosmic situation, but do not forget that this company doesn't know how to reset their passwords, which means they are simply incompetent to the core. Plus OP was fired.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie: also, I work in IT. There are really, really few systems for which the password cannot be recovered (some PKI vaults come to mind) - otherwise for IT **systems** passwords are resettable. Of course if we talk about **data** then you can have encryption and without a password you are done is you did not prepare for that.

Comment: We don't have any information about the capabilities of the business, so you can't possibly say they are incompetent. All we know is one former colleague is contacting the OP asking for passwords. These passwords could be for external systems that the company has no ability to control, and may be a real hassle to get reset. It could also take time. This situation could cause deadlines to be missed and financial penalties.

Comment: If the OP was remiss and acted in such a manner that was to recklessly cause damage to the business, they could very easy get sued to recover damages. It may be far better for the OP to work with the company if they have made a mistake and get that trivially rectified rather than pretend that somehow they forgot the passwords one second after the clocked off on their last day.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie "if they have made a mistake"? The mistake would be to remember the password! You can't possibly be successfully sued for having forgotten proprietary company information (including passwords) for companies you no longer work for. Otherwise, you'd be right and we'd all have to hit ourselves over the head with a baseball bat every time we leave a job!

Comment: @Auspex If you were meant to share credentials in the weeks leading to departure, and you didn't, that would be the mistake. If you made that mistake, you could possibly be compounding your error by refusing to work with your ex-employer to mitigate damage as a result of your mistake. You can absolutely be sued for neglecting to do something.

Comment: @Auspex Note that I am addressing the blanket statement that you should pretend not to remember any passwords. If you think they can reasonably prove in court that you deliberately or recklessly withheld credentials from them, it may be in your best interests to work with the company, lest you find yourself in court.

Comment: @Auspex But, of course, if you actually forgot the credentials, I suppose you should cross your fingers and hope they don't come after you.

Answer (score 3):

When you say "outsourced", do you actually mean *outplaced* (i.e. dismissed), or do you mean you have been transferred to another employer but continue to provide services to your old employer?

If you're not working for your old employer at all anymore, and if you've parted on amicable terms, then it isn't impolite for your colleague to make perhaps one or two brief and non-urgent queries over the following few months.

Compare this to the few moments that might be required to send out a prepared written reference, or field a telephone call from a new employer seeking a reference.

Obviously, they must expect your memory to start to fade, and that contacting ex-employees is a last resort.

Also, if the questions are indeed spurious or used as a shortcut for only modest work, it might be appropriate to remind them that you are no longer employed there. *"Come on, John, they let me go three months ago! I'm sure you could figure this out yourself. I like to do favours, but I only really want to be contacted as a last resort."*.

If the real problem is that you don't really have amicable feelings about your old employer (or indeed this particular colleague), then it might be appropriate to broach that directly. *"You know, John, I was quite surprised to be let go, and I wasn't really happy about it, so I'd like to put it all behind me. You've contacted me X times already about my old work, and I really think this should be the last time"*.

Answer (score 1):

It's reasonable to ask a former employee for a password when the parting was amicable - you'd want someone to return the favor if you were in a tough situation. But this is the kind of thing that should only happen **once**, under dire circumstances (the password cannot be retrieved or reset any other way).

It sounds like you've been more than generous about this, and they need to respect your ability to move on.

Answer (score 1):

### Usually, the answer is no, but there are exceptions.

Plenty of answers have already explained the most common case which is that you should not have to provide a password to a person who no longer employs you, but this is not always the case.  The big exception to this is when your job involves non-core products.  Your company probably had all sorts of company wide products everyone uses.  Office 365, G Suite, etc.  These are things thier IT department should have set up for you when you got there, and that the IT department should be able to properly handle when you leave with or without your cooperation.

However, there are also cases where you may have personally set up products that other employees had nothing to do with at all (due to the unique requirements of your position) and no way of recovering on thier own.  Maybe you were the only one who ever had those credentials.  Maybe you set up something and the 2FA for it is only on your phone.  Things like that can keep an IT team from taking control of the company's intellectual property, even after you've turned in your physical equipment.

In cases like this, you may have a legal requirement to comply after your employment is terminated.  In all likelihood, your contract contained language saying that anything you developed in the employment of that business is thier intellectual property and that it must be turned over at the end of employment. So, if these systems they are asking about would constitute a meaningful failure on your part to turn over thier intellectual property, then refusing to give them the credentials could be seen as Intellectual Property Theft which is a crime punishable with both lawsuits and jailtime in many parts of the world.

There are also other cases where special laws may come in based on the type of information protected by those credentials.  Accusations of Intellectual Property Theft can become much more severe if the intellectual property involved contains financial, medical, classified, or personally identifying information.

So when in doubt, it is usually best to comply anyway.

#### Limitations

Once you turn over the information once, your responsibility is fulfilled.  If they are contacting you over and over for the same credentials, then feel free to refuse to answer thier further questions, but if they keep contacting you about different credentials each time, then you should provided them with those credentials and confirm thier ability to access the account each time until all platforms that you used in their employment are properly turned over.

Answer (score 0):

The OP is being altruistic, that's natural. He is trying to help out the folks he worked with even though the org rather abruptly outsourced him. It shows good character and reflects well on him.

Boring IT policy issues about password management aside, it's OK to help out former coworkers with an occasional piece of information for a few weeks after leaving. Any more than that, however, and the OP risks being taken advantage of.

If he wants to help out further, the best course of action is to ask the former employer to set-up a consulting agreement with a significant hourly rate and hard limits on the number of hours you help them. What that rate is depends on locale, but for a US based tech firm, it could easily be $200+/hr.

Answer (score -9):

Of course your former co-worker can ask you for passwords, how else do they know if you could be trusted with passwords, and give you a good reference.

> My former coworker keeps asking me for passwords. A few I remembered and provided [...]
> This coworker offered to provide a reference (he claimed to be surprised what happened. I actually think he was in on it, but I don't have any proof), so I also feel like I have to stay on his good side. I only have two other references...

LOL! ROFL! **Now you are certain to be getting a strong *negative* reference**, expect your employment to be listed on your credit report for the next few years and kiss your current career BYE-BYE!  You just gave sensitive information to someone potentially not authorized, you fell for their trap and now you will have to pay the price, you may even be subject to legal consequences.

I once worked for someone who didn't like me... turns out they hired me for a few hours just so they could list themselves on my credit report and be a negative referral.  Trust me, once they get on your credit report, there is no saving your career, it is over.  In the USA they can say whatever they want so long as you can't prove it to be false (i.e. slander).  If you emailed or communicated the passwords over a phone line then they have actual proof.  Seeing as how your employer and coworkers did not like you, none of these things happening to you would surprise me.

Comment: I am not a "new contributor", I just value privacy enough to only use an account a few times per site.

Comment: There are some good points in this answer, but overall tone and delivery is not ideal. I would suggest that this Answer should be re-written to focus on the point that some companies and jurisdictions may prohibit an ex-employee giving out any data (even if asked for by the company).

Comment: I am not a lawyer and I know that some employers check credit reports during the hiring process, but I'm pretty sure that's not how credit reports work.

Comment: I think you've confused a credit report with a background check.